# How to add a udf as a stage in PySpark ML pipeline?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

sample df:

```
+-----------+
|pred_vector|
+-----------+
| [0.5, 0.6]|                  
| [0.7, 0.8]|                   
| [1.1, 1.5]|                                 
+-----------+
```

I use the following function to extract value at ith index from the dense vector and 
convert to float:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import DoubleType
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit, udf

def ith_(v, i):
    try:
        return float(v[i])
    except ValueError:
        return None

ith = udf(ith_, DoubleType())

df.select(ith("features", lit(1))).show()

## +-----------------+
## |ith_(features, 1)|
## +-----------------+
## |              0.5|
## |              0.7|
## |              1.1|
## +-----------------+
```

Using the following code I want to build a custom transformer that I can append in my pipeline stages. It is supposed to extract the first value from the vector in pred_vector column in df, convert it to float and save it in a new column in df

```
# CUSTOM TRANSFORMER ----------------------------------------------------------------
class TypeConverter(Transformer):
    """
    A custom Transformer which converts 'pred_vector' column dense vector type to float.
    """

    def __init__(self):
        super(TypeConverter, self).__init__()


    def _transform(self, df: DataFrame) -> DataFrame:
        df = df.withColumn("new_column", ith("pred_vector"))
        return df
```

```
df:
+-----------+-----------+
|pred_vector|new_column |
+-----------+-----------+
| [0.5, 0.6]| 0.5       |          
| [0.7, 0.8]| 0.7       |            
| [1.1, 1.5]| 1.1       |                         
+-----------+-----------+
```

How can I fit the udf in the custom transformer?

Comment: why use a udf when you can use element_at https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.element_at.

Comment: element_at is used to extract from an array according to the documentation, I am trying to extract from a dense vector, also the other issue is appending this step in my pipeline